# Impossible to display index.php page, wrong apache2 config

Tags: apache

My /var folder has the following structure:

```
/var
   /www
      v1/
         releases/
             2017061/
                public/
                   index.php
             2017062/
                public/
                   index.php
             ...
```

When i open the following url in my browser i get a 500.
http://myserver.com/v1/releases/2017061/public/

Here is my apache config file :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin me@mydomain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www

  <Directory /var/www/>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: If you create a new folder in www and put in one index.php file
is it executing? Can you take a try ?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay I created a new html folder with a single index.html file inside www folder and i well see the index.html file in the browser when i put the correct url